# Probability of bounded roots

Tags: pr.probability, polynomials

Pick a random degree $n$ polynomial $$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0\in\Bbb K[x]$$ uniformly with $-m<a_i<m$.

Pick $m'\in[1,m)$.

When $\Bbb K=\Bbb R$ what is the probability that $f(x)=0$ at some $x$ with $|x|<m'$ when $(1)$ $x\in\Bbb R$ and $(2)$ $x\in\Bbb C$ holds?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Do you ask for the probabilty that there is a root inside the unit disc/interval? Or are you asking the probability that for a specific $x$, $f(x)=0$? For the former question, a pretty detailed answer is available, by Dembo, Poonen, Shao and myself.

Comment: @oferzeitouni three cases interval, disc and finite set of points in interval/disc.

Comment: @oferzeitouni so in short the former. which theorem specifically in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0006113v1.pdf?

Comment: 1.1 basically, it is stated as the probability of no real root at all but that probability is asymptotically just the square of no real root in [-1,1].

Comment: The event of no root in the unit disc is a large deviations event, and has an exponential in n^2 vanishing probability.

Comment: @oferzeitouni I do not see $[−1,1]$ I only see no real roots. may be you could just elaborate your thoughts as an answer for both $[-1,1]$ and unit disc cases?

Comment: If you look at the proof you will see that the probability of no real roots in the  [-1,1] interval is just the square-root of the no real roots at all probability. For the disc it is a completely different story, the probability is exponential in N^2 instead of polynomial. Unfortunately, I do not have the time at the moment to write a detailed answer, hence the comments.

Comment: @oferzeitouni So probability no roots in unit disc is roughly $C*exp(-N^2)$ and probability no roots in $[-1,1]$ is roughly $C*N^{-b/2}$ for some constant b? Would you know *numerically* what the constant might be (such as $b>2$ or something?

Comment: The value of $b$ is known numerically to be around 3/16, some rigorous bounds were obtained by Shao and the late Li; see Dembo's slides that also explain quite well what is going on: http://math.iisc.ernet.in/~imi/downloads/Dembo_bangalore_100113.pdf.

Comment: For the complex case, the exponential in $N^2$ is for the probability to have no zeros in a disc of radius $1+\epsilon$, sorry fot the error in my earlier comment (the result follows from an LDP for the empirical measure of roots, obtained by Zelditch and myself). For a disc of radius 1 exactly, I am not sure of the exact rate, I expect that it is at least exponential in $N$ but am not 100% sure.

Comment: @oferzeitouni disc of radius 1+eps contains radius 1 disc. so if prob is O(exp(-N^2)) for 1+eps it should be at most this for radius 1.

Comment: no. I am always writing the probability of NO root in the region, which is 1 minus the probability you asked about .

Comment: See also https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9501224

Comment: @PhilippWacker I saw that result before. I was not sure if it is applicable here.